# Simple_DOM question about finding classes

Tags: php, html, class, object, simpledom

I am trying to do a simple extraction, but I keep ending up with unpredictable results.

I have this HTML code

```
<div class="thread" style="margin-bottom:25px;"> 

<div class="message"> 

<span class="profile">Suzy Creamcheese</span> 

<span class="time">December 22, 2010 at 11:10 pm</span> 

<div class="msgbody"> 

<div class="subject">New digs</div> 

Hello thank you for trying our soap. <BR>  Jim.

</div> 
</div> 


<div class="message reply"> 

<span class="profile">Lars Jörgenmeier</span> 

<span class="time">December 22, 2010 at 11:45 pm</span> 

<div class="msgbody"> 

I never sold you any soap.

</div> 

</div> 

</div>
```

And I am trying to extract the outertext from "msgbody" but only when the "profile" is equal to something. Like so.

```
$contents  = $html->find('.msgbody');
$elements = $html->find('.profile'); 

           $length = sizeof($contents);

           while($x != sizeof($elements)) {

            $var = $elements[$x]->outertext;

                        //If profile = the right name
            if ($var = $name) {

                                    $text = $contents[$x]->outertext;
                echo $text;

            }



            $x++;
         }
```

I get text from the wrong profiles, not the ones with the associations I need.
Is there a way to just pull the desired info with one line of code?

Like if span-profile = "correct name" then 
pull its div-msgbody

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I'm going to go with [DOMXpath](https://www.php.net/domxpath) on this one. I'm not sure what 'outer text' is supposed to mean, but I'll go with this requirement:

> Like if span-profile = "correct name"
> then pull its div-msgbody

First off, Here's the minified HTML test case I used:

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="thread" style="margin-bottom:25px;"> 

<div class="message"> 

<span class="profile">Suzy Creamcheese</span> 

<span class="time">December 22, 2010 at 11:10 pm</span> 

<div class="msgbody"> 

<div class="subject">New digs</div> 

Hello thank you for trying our soap. <BR>  Jim.

</div> 
</div> 


<div class="message reply"> 

<span class="profile">Lars Jörgenmeier</span> 

<span class="time">December 22, 2010 at 11:45 pm</span> 

<div class="msgbody"> 

I never sold you any soap.

</div> 

</div> 

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So, we'll make an XPath query for this. Let's show the whole thing, then break it down:

```
$messages = $xpath->query("//span[@class='profile' and contains(.,'$profile_name')]/../div[@class='msgbody']");
```

The break down:

> //span
>
> Give me spans
>
> //span[@class='profile']
>
> Give me spans where the class is
> profile
>
> //span[@class='profile' and
> contains(.,'$profile_name')]
>
> Give me spans where the class is
> profile and the inside of the span
> contains `$profile_name`, which is the
> name you're after
>
> //span[@class='profile' and
> contains(.,'$profile_name')]/../
>
> Give me spans where the class is
> profile and the inside of the span
> contains `$profile_name`, which is the
> name you're after now go up a level,
> which gets us to `<div class="message">`
>
> //span[@class='profile' and
> contains(.,'$profile_name')]/../div[@class='msgbody']
>
> Give me spans where the class is
> profile and the inside of the span
> contains `$profile_name`, which is the
> name you're after now go up a level,
> which gets us to `<div class="message">` and finally, give me
> all divs under `<div class="message">`
> where the class is msgbody

Now then, here's a sample of the PHP code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("test.html");

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$profile_name = 'Lars Jörgenmeier';
$messages = $xpath->query("//span[@class='profile' and contains(.,'$profile_name')]/../div[@class='msgbody']");
foreach ($messages as $message) {
  echo trim("{$message->nodeValue}") . "\n";
}
```

XPath is very powerful like this. I recommend looking over a [basic tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/xpathtutorial.php), then you can check the [XPath standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) if you want to see more advanced usage.

Comment: whoa man that is lot of concise info. thanks for the xpath conversion. i love Simple_DOM but it hemorrhage memry!

Comment: Also, I've noticed you have to insert this in the header to get those special characters, such as `Jörgenmeier` to pass XPath.

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
`

Comment: @user734063 hmm interesting.. you probably only need the `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" ....>` bit to be honest. It most likely worked for me since I saved the file locally and have UTF-8 setup by default.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Simple HTML DOM working example.

I changed your example html so there would be more than one profile for Suzy Creamcheese as follows: (file: test_class_class.htm)

```
 <div class="message"> 
   <span class="profile">Suzy Creamcheese</span> 
   <span class="time">December 22, 2010 at 11:10 pm</span> 
   <div class="msgbody"> 
     <div class="subject">New digs</div> 
       Hello thank you for trying our soap. <BR>  Jim.
     </div> 
   </div> 

   <div class="message reply"> 
     <span class="profile">Lars Jörgenmeier</span> 
     <span class="time">December 22, 2010 at 11:45 pm</span> 
     <div class="msgbody"> 
       I never sold you any soap.
     </div> 
   </div> 
 </div>

 <div class="message"> 
   <span class="profile">Suzy Yogurt</span> 
   <span class="time">December 22, 2010 at 11:10 pm</span> 
   <div class="msgbody"> 
     <div class="subject">No Creamcheese</div> 
       This is not Suzy Creamcheese <BR>  Jim.
     </div> 
   </div> 

   <div class="message reply"> 
     <span class="profile">Suzy Creamcheese</span> 
     <span class="time">December 22, 2010 at 11:45 pm</span> 
     <div class="msgbody"> 
       A reply from Suzy Creamcheese.
     </div> 
   </div> 
 </div>

</div>
```

Here is my test using Simple HTML DOM:
    include('simple_html_dom.php');

```
function getMessage_for_profile($iUrl,$iProfile)
{
    // create HTML DOM
    $html = file_get_html($iUrl);

    // get text elements
    $aoProfile = $html->find('span[class=profile]'); 
    echo "Found ".count($aoProfile)." profiles.<br />";

    foreach ($aoProfile as $key=>$oProfile)
    {
      if ($oProfile->plaintext == $iProfile)
      {
        echo "<b>Profile ".$key.": ".$oProfile->plaintext."</b><br />";
// Using $e->next_sibling ()
        $oCurrent = $oProfile;
        while ($oNext = $oCurrent->next_sibling())
        {
           if ( $oNext->class == "msgbody" )
           {
             echo "<hr />";
             echo $oNext->outertext;
             echo "<hr />";
           }
           $oCurrent = $oNext;
        }
      }         
    }

    // clean up memory
    $html->clear();
    unset($html);

    return;
}
// --------------------------------------------
// test it!
// user_agent header...
ini_set('user_agent', 'My-Application/2.5');

getMessage_for_profile('test_class_class.htm','Suzy Creamcheese');
echo "<br /><br /><br />";
getMessage_for_profile('test_class_class.htm','Suzy Yogurt');
```

My output was:

```
Found 4 profiles.
Profile 0: Suzy Creamcheese
--------------------------------
New digs
Hello thank you for trying our soap.
Jim.
---------------------------------
Profile 3: Suzy Creamcheese
---------------------------------
A reply from Suzy Creamcheese.
---------------------------------



Found 4 profiles.
Profile 2: Suzy Yogurt
---------------------------------
No Creamcheese
This is not Suzy Creamcheese
Jim.
---------------------------------
```

See it can be done with Simple HTML DOM and since I already know how the DOM works... or enough to get in trouble... I did not have to learn any knew syntax!